# Translated dates in Views

Tags: datetime, i18n-l10n

I have a View which outputs the node creation date. But the site is multilingual. The problem is that I cannot choose a custom date format, as the Views just accepts one of a list. If I use a custom PHP format like j F Y (day month year in friendly format), I have prepositions, for example, in Spanish, that I cannot use: it should read "18 de Enero de 2015" instead of "18 Enero 2015" and if I put "j \d\e F Y", this will show a "de" which should not be present in other languages, like English.

Is there some module to just translate dates to multilanguage human friendly dates ? As I said, trying with Regions, Date Formats, Custom Date Format, etc., I cannot achieve what I need. If I use other formats, I have the extra time displayed, which I don't want, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many alternate date formats as you like. See this page for help: https://www.drupal.org/node/1600786